# Mapbox SDK Registry Token is null

Tags: flutter, gradle, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I'm experiencing issues installing mapbox_gl plugin on my flutter app...

I did follow the official instrctions from there :

https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl

But whenever I hit flutter run I get the same message :

`SDK Registry token is null. See README.md for more information.`

Which leads to :

`Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':mapbox_gl' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Looks like a gradle issue... What am I missing ?

I'm using the beta flutter channel and running with --no-sound-null-safety

Here's my code :

android/build.graddle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username). 
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = "[Yes I checked this token multiple times]"
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android/app/build.graddle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.mobile_coring"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    // Add the block below if you're using Kotlin
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.1'
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_login: ^1.1.0
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
  location: ^4.1.1
  mapbox_gl: ^0.12.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
  - assets/images/maorie.png
  - assets/images/tiro.png
  - assets/images/coccinelle.jpg

  fonts:
    - family: Cabin
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Cabin-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/Cabin-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Cabin-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
          weight: 600
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/Cabin-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Cabin-BoldItalic.ttf
          weight: 700
          style: italic

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problems installing this plugin as well
finally, I managed to import and run **mapbox_gl: ^0.10.0**
Just follow these steps:

1. In your android/app/build.gradle set

> compileSdkVersion 29

> minSdkVersion 20

> targetSdkVersion 29

2. In android/build.gradle set

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

3. In android/gradle/wrapper/gradle_wrapper.properties set

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip

4. Finally in your pubspec.yaml import

> mapbox_gl: ^0.10.0

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try that as soon as possible !

Comment: Hey @BriceLeRoux. Did the above solution work for you?

Answer (score 7):

Add this line to your gradle.properties file:

```
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=YOUR MAPBOX DOWNLOADS ACCESS TOKEN
```

Follow this documentation to create your token:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/